# Product with specified super products SKU not found in rows

Tags: magento1.9.2.3

I am getting this error when trying to import my products from backend through `csv`.

> file format: csv. error getting: Product with specified super products
>   SKU not found in rows: 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31,
>   32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48,
>   49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65,
>   66, 67, 68, 69, 70

Can any one help me to solve it?
thank you

Answer (score 1):

The numbers are the lines in you CSV that yield the error. The products you specified there do simply not exist. Always take care of creating simples before you attach them to a configurable.

Out of the comments: Restructure your csv to ensure : simples first

Comment: What should i do now?

Comment: i am trying to move my old website products to the new website with help of export and import. but exporting gives this error how should i fix it? as my old website have this products

Comment: Oh. The idea is good, but does not work, at least if you have some "complex" products. Than Importing an Export does not produce the same data you tried to export.
Solution could be: move database and update. Or be vary about the problem that exist with importing. Than you only have to fix those.